# Spring boot UUID primary key entity doesn't show right id after created

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

So I have entity with UUID as primary key. After I create the entity in my service, the response return wrong id.

My Role entity

```
package denny.study.stock.entity

import denny.study.stock.util.converter.JsonToMapConverter
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp
import java.util.*
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    var id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID()

    @Column
    var name: String = ""

    @Column
    var slug: String = ""

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = JsonToMapConverter::class)
    var permissions: MutableMap<String, Boolean>? = null

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @CreationTimestamp
    var createdAt: Date = Date()

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    var updatedAt: Date? = null

}
```

My store method in role service

```
    override fun store(roleRequest: RoleRequest): RoleResponse {
        val role = Role().apply {
            name = roleRequest.name
            slug = roleRequest.slug
            permissions = roleRequest.permissions
        }

        roleRepository.save(role)

        return RoleResponse(role)
    }
```

My Role response

```
package denny.study.stock.model.response.role

import denny.study.stock.entity.Role

class RoleResponse(role: Role) {

    var id = role.id

    var name = role.name

    var slug = role.slug

    var permissions = role.permissions

}
```

the json response return id "f95bddf6-eb22-49bb-b8e6-5eb819603fa9"

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "OK",
    "data": {
        "id": "f95bddf6-eb22-49bb-b8e6-5eb819603fa9",
        "name": "Role 1",
        "slug": "role-1",
        "permissions": {
            "asd": true,
            "dsa": false
        }
    }
}
```

while in DB it stored as "87596692-7ee9-4ecb-a425-3b1372d901f4". Do you know why It return the wrong id? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please check the executed SQL statement. logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.basicbinder=trace and logging.level.org.hibernate.sql=debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `@GeneratedValue` annotation and also assigning `UUID.randomUUID()` to the `id` attribute. Either use one or the other, not both.

If you want the ID to be generated by the persistence provider then keep `@GeneratedValue` and remove `@GenericGenerator` (which is a Hibernate annotation) and `UUID.randomUUID()`. If you want to do that on your own then remove `@GeneratedValue` and `@GenericGenerator`.